# Which type of material would I have to study to get a deep understanding of the ionization phenomenon?

Tags: atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, education, ions

I've been collecting basic information about the phenomenon of ionization. I know what it is and its sources and types (as well as the type of particles that can cause it). However, it is my goal to attain a deeper understanding of this subject. Therefore, my question is: which type of learning material would I have to study in order to achieve this goal?

I'm guessing I would have to dive into books about atomic and molecular physics, but I don't know where to start or if there is a book or set dedicated to the subject. Do you validate this approach?

I apologize if this is a hard question to answer but I'm clueless of the path that needs to be taken. Feel free to close or delete it.

Comment: trust the PDB, and references within: https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf

Comment: @JEB Good! Thank you. You've reminded me to search more in the 'interactions of radiation with matter' topic. It is certainly a step in the right direction.